# Cognitive Services Face API delete person data issue

Tags: face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am using cognitive services face api for login functionality in my application.  Once logged in successfully, user is given option to delete the account and all user data has to be deleted permanently. To delete person in person group and faces, I am using delete api(https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/persongroups/{personGroupId}/persons/{personId}).

I am expecting that delete api will remove person and faces data which is working fine in some cases but in some cases, I am getting person id in response from identify api for a person who no longer exists in person group.

So issue is that Identify api is still getting some data to identity the person.How can I fix this? Do I need to use some other api along with delete person api?

Answer (score 1):

The model training process is a computationally expensive process, relatively speaking, and therefore does not occur automatically after a person add/remove/modify.  You need to train explicitly.

Can you confirm that the deleted person is no longer returned after one more call to [train](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395249)?

Comment: Hi @cthrash , I can confirm even after training it is returning a personID after deleting